# AngularJS ng-options filter by array value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need some help figuring out how I can use the AngularJS filter to only show the options that match my condition.

I have the below array.

```
var users = [
  {'id':0, 'name':'John',  'roles':['Admin']},
  {'id':1, 'name':'Alice', 'roles':['Admin', 'Tech']},
  {'id':2, 'name':'Sam':   'roles':['Tech']}
]
```

I render all the users on a `<select>` list with the below code. But I only want to show the users who's role is "Tech". I went through a few other answers on here but they all use the filter with an object, I'm trying this with an array.

```
<select data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users"></select>
```

I've tried to only show the options with `data-ng-if="item.roles.indexOf('Tech') > -1"` on the `<select>` tag but that condition is never met so the dropdown is not shown at all (which makes sense).

I also tried to use `data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users | filter:{item.roles:'Tech'}"` with the filter, but that fails with an AngularJS parse error.

Not sure how I can filter by array values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in your last attempt is correct but you have a small syntax error. Try the following

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users | filter: { roles: ('Tech') }"></select>
```

You can also create your own custom filter function for this

html

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users | filter:customFilter"></select>
```

js

```
$scope.customFilter = function(row){
    if(row.roles.includes("Tech")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uIrT2E8Ze0fsu77fOj8V?p=preview)**